# Meaning of に in this sentence

Tags: particle-に

> 色白の肌**に**優しそうな目がほほ笑んでいる。
>   Her light complexion ?? kind looking eyes were smiling.

Is this に simply 'in'? i.e. "Her kind looking eyes were smiling **in** her pale skin." That sounds a bit weird.

My other thought was that it might be "due to" i.e. the fact that her skin is pale makes her eyes stand out more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two interpretations:

- "in"
  her eyes are located in the middle of the extent of her light skin
- "plus"
  she has light skin as well as kind looking eyes

If you take the second interpretation, the sentence becomes grammatically incohesive, but sounds not bad in literary writing.

In fact, I was able to find an example of similar "in her pale skin" in a novel called [Kings, Queens, and All Their Things: A Drag Shergi Mystery](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=MMRQCAAAQBAJ&lpg=PT15&ots=PcYsKUtNEU&dq=%22in%20her%20pale%20skin%22&hl=ja&pg=PT15#v=onepage&q=%22in%20her%20pale%20skin%22&f=false), so I guess it's not immediately a weird English ... is it?

> She had scarlet hair cut around her face then the rest fell down her back. There were brown eyes **in her pale skin**.